# WPF MVVM application source code obfuscation

Tags: wpf

I am working on a WPF application using MVVM architecture, i would request you all to guide me the best solution for obfuscating app source code, best obfuscator for WPF and any known issues which can be encountered while obfuscating wpf app source code.

Thank you all in advance for your time.

Comment: One question worth considering is whether the WPF component of your application actually has anything worth obfuscating.  If there is any 'secret sauce' IP in your application, it's likely in a separate assembly that does not contain any XAML content, which can be obfuscated using standard tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the most prolific obfuscator for .NET
Supposedly this product can handle some obfuscation of the related XAML code, but it appears that this is not always the case.
http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview

Of all of these obfuscators, it seems that only Dotfuscator offers any type of XAML support, and I have not heard of others being able to support it.  I suppose that the nature of databinding in WPF makes the renaming part of obfuscation technically impossible, or difficult enough that nobody can fully support it.

Based on personal experience, I have had limited success with obfuscation of WPF / XAML applications so I don't bother with even trying anymore.

Comment: The part of the question about WPF and MVVM is important. You can't just spout the standard information about obfuscators, because WPF databinding introduces its own concerns -- specifically, databinding by property name. If the obfuscator renamed a property and didn't somehow fix up the XAML, the program would break. I think OP was looking for answers that would help address this.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question.  I have made my answer specific to the XAML part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time! i think i have to test this to get a conclusion, i will downloaded the most popular top 3 obfuscators and test with my app. I will let you know the results !

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I came upon ConfuseEx, a free open-source obfuscator that does the job for WPF apps and more. It seems to be very powerful, effective and customizable.

[ConfuseEx on Github](http://yck1509.github.io/ConfuserEx/)

Answer (score 0):

[Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) has full support for WPF and Silverlight. If it renames any API during the obfuscation process, it will also automatically update the references found in the XAML/BAML to those renamed API.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developer of Crypto Obfuscator.

Comment: is it also able to handle Databinding via Properties and Element? Like `{Binding myPropertie }` or `{Binding ElementName = mySourceElement, Path = Text }`