# Can MVVMCross work with code obfuscation?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

Using MVVMCross with Xamarin, Can I obfuscate the view models or do I need to leave them unobfuscated?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly common Mvvm question - e.g. in questions like [WPF MVVM application source code obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498158/wpf-mvvm-application-source-code-obfuscation)

There are obfuscation techniques you can take - especially with obfuscators which allow you to mark certain classes or properties as fixed. If you find one of these, and if it works with Xamarin's tools, then you will need to mark:

- the ViewModel class names as immutable
- the ViewModel public property names as immutable
- the IMvxViewModel public method names as immutable (e.g. methods like `Init`)
- all Reflection-used class names in the UI is immutable - e.g. View names
- any class names you yourself are using for reflection (e.g. if you are using `Service` as a postfix convention).

If you've used separated your Views and ViewModels by namespace, then I expect this would actually be quite quick to do, but I don't have any personal experience with obfuscators on  Xamarin.